# Htaccess RedirectMatch proper use

Tags: .htaccess

I have my .htaccess file setup like the following.  It's a simple concept where all requests get forwarded to the cgi-bin/controller.rb except for those requests for anything in /images, /css, /javascripts, or /cgi-bin

I also want the root to just be redirected to /index/show but that's the part which is erroring.  It just keeps infinitely redirecting to /index/showindex/showindex/show...

Can anyone explain why my redirectmatch doesn't work?

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /index/show

ErrorDocument 404 /404

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascripts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/controller.rb?%{QUERY_STRING}&page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using RedirectMatch and RewriteRule at the same time. Those are different modules and are applied at different times in the request-flow. You can achieve the same using only RewriteRule's:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/show [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index/show [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/show [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascripts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/controller.rb?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Optionally use `RewriteRule ^$ /index/show [L,R=301]` if you really want the redirect, instead of leaving the address bar nice and clean.

Also remember to clear the browsers cache, as the Permanent redirect are cached very aggressively.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Your answer helped me understand a bit more about how htaccess files work.  Thanks.

Comment: Why avoid using RedirectMatch and RewriteRule at the same time? That they are different modules and are applied at different times in the request-flow does not constitute a reason.

Comment: @user2407309 Avoiding hard to explain erratic behavior, that could be different on different servers, seems like a good practice.